# Docker not saving images and writing to textfile (Python application)

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

I created a Python application that receives images from an email message and stores it locally under a folder called **Images**. It also writes some config data to **dict.txt**. When I run the application without Docker (using Pycharm IDE), this works. However, this expected behaviour does not occur when I use docker.

[ImageLink: Directory structure (Pycharm IDE)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qnm5H.png)

**Directory structure (container):**

```
IntermediateService
├─── Dockerfile
├─── requirements.txt
└─── src
     └─── emailAccountA.py
     └─── emailAccountB.py
     └─── main.py
     └─── dict.txt
     └─── Images
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
# set base image (host OS)
FROM python:3.8.5

# set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /code

# copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt .

# install dependencies
RUN pip --default-timeout=100000 install -r requirements.txt

# copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY src/ .

# command to run on container start
CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
```

**I run the following docker commands:**

```
docker build -t intermediateservice .
docker run intermediateservice
```

The container builds and runs without any issue, just does not write to **dict.txt** and save the downloaded images to the **Images folder** (both textfile and folder are always empty). What needs to be done to resolve this issue?

Comment: It writes to the filesystem _inside_ the container, which is lost when the container exits.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks. What modifications need to be done to the dockerfile or docker commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @john-gordon said it writes to the filesystem inside the container, which is lost when the container exits. You need to mount your folder inside the container when running it:

```sh
docker run -v $(pwd)/Images:/code/Images intermediateservice
```

Answer (score 1):

Containers are stateless so all data is lost when the container stops. Additionally, writing to a file inside the container isn't very practical.

In this case, it's best to mount a host folder into the container when launching `docker run`. For example, this mounts an `images` sub-directory into the container's `/code/images` directory:

```
-v $PWD/images:/code/images
```

(`$PWD` isn't valid on Windows, so you need the full path, e.g. `/c/myproject/images/`).

I wrote a **[Docker for Web Developers](https://dockerwebdev.com/)** book and video course because I couldn't find good tutorials for beginners which showed how to create local development environments. It'll help. There's a 50% Black Friday sale now on.